# How to load TabBarController or UIViewController based on first load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

sorry if this is kind of a duplicate question but I have looked at many questions and haven't found the right answer.

Basically if the app is on first launch, a UIViewController with a How To screen should be loaded. If it is not first launch, it loads a Tab Bar Controller.

To do this, I have a UIViewController as the initial view controller, and then modal segues to the tab bar and uiviewcontroller

[image]

The two modal segues are called pushTabBar and pushHowToUse.

Here is the code for "firstviewcontroller"

```
@implementation FirstViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self isFirstRun];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (BOOL) isFirstRun
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"isFirstRun"])
    {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"pushTabBar" sender: self];

        return NO;

    }

    [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"isFirstRun"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"right before");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"pushHowToUse" sender: self];



    return YES;
}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushTabBar"]) {

        GetInfoViewController *getInfoViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSLog(@"loadtabbar");

    }
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushHowToUse"]) {

         TutorialViewController *tutorialViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSLog(@"loadhowto");

    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I am not sure what to push/load for the tab bar controller:

```
  GetInfoViewController *getInfoViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
```

is the viewcontroller for the first tab bar I want to load.

Am I doing this correctly? Should I be using a navigation root controller?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the FirstViewController if its only purpose is to decide which other controller to present (BTW, calling a modal segue pushToTabBar is a confusing name -- you're doing a presentation not a push). You can do the logic in the viewDidAppear method of the controller in the first tab of the tab bar controller. If it's the first launch, present the TutorialViewController modally with no animation so it will be the first thing the user sees. When the user is done with the tutorial, dismiss that controller, and you be back to that first tab view controller. You should hookup a segue from that controller at index 0 of the tab bar controller to the TutorialViewController.

Comment: thanks. this method makes a lot more sense than what i was following before.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off doing the segue from the Tab Bar controller. That way, you can just dismiss the modal presentation and when the tutorial segue goes away, you're already at the tab bar.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by doing the segue from tabbar..how do I link tutorial segue to tab bar?

Comment: The answer you accepted was what I was thinking. I just didn't specify it clearly enough.